# Use redux store with Tampermonkey

Tags: reactjs, tampermonkey

I need to be able to read the state of a react application from a Tampermonkey script. I've been looking at how [React Dev Tools](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools) does it, but haven't been able to figure it out.

I'm pretty sure there is a way to do this, since the extension does not require anything from the react page to work to my knowledge.

So how can I access react state from an external script? I can not modify the code running on the page.

Comment: Do you want to just read what the state currently is from the dev console or do you want some other type of control?

Comment: Initial state and then subscribe to state updates if that's possible.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there is a nicer way to do have all the features you're looking for, but i only know how to get `store.getState` to be available in the dev console at all points in time:

```
//What my store looks like
const createStore = state =>
  createStore(RootReducer, state)
const store = createStore()
// place this in the same file you use your provider and name it what you named your store.
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  window.store = store
}
```

You can now use `store.getState` in your dev console

```
store.getState()
```

But personally, I make a getter out of `store.getState()`

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  Object.defineProperty(window, 'store', () => {
    get: function() {
      return store.getState()
    }
  })
}
```

When I do it this way, I only have to type in

```
store
```

to have it return my current redux store.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I can not modify the source code of the page.